# get a list of Gridview checked items

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a dynamic `GridView` of students that number of rows it depends on database information

[image: example of my page/table]

I want that after I press the button i will get a list of ONLY checked `PersonID` in array/list.
I don't know how to write this JavaScript/jQuery function.

CheckBox:

```
<asp:CheckBox CssClass="chk" ID="Checkbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PersonID") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
```

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="myClosure1()" />
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myClosure1() {
    $('.chk').each(function () {
        var chkbox = $(this).children('input').get(0);
        if (chkbox.checked) {

        }
    });
}

</script>
```

I'm not sure it even gets inside the `$('.chk').each`

Edit **example to the picture I upload it will publish numbers 1,2,4 beacuse i check them**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that case, I'll add another hidden filed control. Then the rendered output will be like this -

```
<span class="chk">
   <input id="GridView1_Checkbox_0" type="checkbox" name="GridView1$ctl02$Checkbox">
      <label for="GridView1_Checkbox_0">1</label>
</span>
<input type="hidden" name="GridView1$ctl02$HiddenField1" 
      id="GridView1_HiddenField1_0" value="1">
```

ASP.NET Checkbox control is rendered inside span tag, so you will need to access them as `.chk input` in jQuery.

```
<button type="button" id="btnAll">Select All</button>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    runat="server" DataKeyNames="PersonID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PersonID" HeaderText="PersonID" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox CssClass="chk" ID="Checkbox"
                    runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PersonID") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenField1"
                    Value='<%# Bind("PersonID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var personIDs;
    $("#btnAll").click(function () {
        personIDs = []; // Clear data
        $(".chk input:checked").each(function () {
            // 'this' is a checkbox, so we need to go up to parent span tag.
            personIDs.push($(this).parent().next('input[type=hidden]').val());
        });
        $("#result").text(personIDs);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: friend , sorry you  understand me wrong,,, i wanted that after i Press a button it will make me a array/allert  of all the PersonalID numbers that i checked.. so example in the picture that i upload , he will make array of numbers 1,2,4 because i check them

Comment: thank you very much... 
if really i didnt understand where i put the first part of the code (with the span) .. and  how i use the hidden field ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Each row of the table
$("#table tr").each(function(){ 
        // get checkbox id and look for CheckStatus.
});
```

Comment: the problem Because GridView  is Dynamic.. i not really have ID .. (number of rows are not know to me)

Comment: Please avoid dumping just a code. Please add more related description regarding your answer.